# Bootstrap colums wont align horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add some Bootstrap elements to my portfolio after the fact and im running into some issues. My only columns added so far are in the top in the "welcome-section" Lines 40-52. They will not align horizontally. Everything I see to troubleshoot seems easy enough but trying different containers, rows, sizes, gutters, and styles etc. has not given me any results.

Could it be an element in my style.css file that's causing the columns to not align? If so are you able to see the issue? I always struggle going back to freshen up sites with new code.

I really appreciate your help. I've been stumped!

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: roboto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
/* nav*/

/* sections */

#welcome-section {
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
 #hi {
    padding-left: 5vw;
    font-size: 200vh;
    font-size: 12vw;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    padding-top: 4vh;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 0.9em;
    color: white;
}

#job-title {
  padding-left: 5vw;
    font-size: min(3vw, 36px);
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 0.9em;
    color: white;
}

#projects {
    background-color: #344966;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.projects-section-header {
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#contact {
    background-color: #6D9DC5;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
#welcome-section {
    background: linear-gradient(92deg, #2e3192, #1bffff);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    -webkit-animation: bluegradient 59s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: bluegradient 59s ease infinite;
    animation: bluegradient 59s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bluegradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 51%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bluegradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 51%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}
@keyframes bluegradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 51%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}
/*  

1. Tesla Product Page
https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/MWrEErN

2. Tribute Page
https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/rNpzdzG

3. Street Fighter jQuery
http://darkstar93.github.io/jquery-streetfighter/main.html

4. Warcraft Quiz App
http://darkstar93.github.io/quiz/

5. Instagram API Hack
http://darkstar93.github.io/instagramapihack/

6. Input Survey Form
https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/rNpwROz
*/

/* Custom properties/variables  */

:root {
    --main-white: #f0f0f0;
    --main-red: #be3144;
    --main-blue: #8797B2;
    --main-gray: #000807;
}
/* Base reset */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* box-sizing and font sizing */

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
@media (max-width: 75em) {
    html {
        font-size: 60%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 61.25em) {
    html {
        font-size: 58%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
    html {
        font-size: 55%;
    }
}
/* Base styles */

body {
    font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    /* 18px */
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: var(--main-white);
}
h1 {
    font-size: 6rem;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 4.2rem;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--main-white);
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Projects section */

.projects-section {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10rem 2rem;
    background: var(--main-blue);
}
.projects-section-header {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto 6rem auto;
    var(--main-white);
}
@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
    .projects-section-header {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
}

.projects-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 4rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
    padding: 28px;
}
@media (max-width: 30.625em) {
    .projects-section {
        padding: 6rem 1rem;
    }
    .projects-grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
.project {
    background: var(--main-gray);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.code {
    color: var(--main-gray);
    transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
}
.project:hover .code {
    color: #ff7f50;
}
.project-image {
    height: calc(100% - 6.8rem);
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.project-title {
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.btn-show-all {
    font-size: 2rem;
    background: var(--main-gray);
    transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}
.btn-show-all:hover {
    background: var(--main-red);
}
.btn-show-all:hover>i {
    transform: translateX(2px);
}
.btn-show-all>i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
    footer {
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
/*blinking */

.blinking-cursor {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
    -moz-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
    -ms-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
    -o-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
    animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}
@keyframes "blink" {
    from, to {
        color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        color: white;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
    from, to {
        color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        color: black;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
    from, to {
        color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        color: black;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes "blink" {
    from, to {
        color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        color: black;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes "blink" {
    from, to {
        color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        color: black;
    }
}
.contact-links {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.contact-details {
    font-size: 3rem;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.contact-details:hover {
    transform: translateY(8px);
    color: black;
}
i {
    color: white;
}
#work {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
}


.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  .nav {
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .nav-list {
    margin: 0 1rem;
  }
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  background: var(--main-blue);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
          
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <nav class="nav" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="#welcome-section">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
           
  
        </nav>
        <section id="welcome-section">
            <div class="container-fluid"
            <div class="row justify-content-start" id="name">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: rgb(136, 84, 20);">
                <h1 id="hi">Hi<br>
                I am<br>
                Thomas</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 justify-content-end" style="background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);"><p>I'm highly motivated and passionate about development and creative design. I challenge myself every day to be a little better and increase my skills. </p></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <h1 id="job-title"></h1>
        </section>
        <section class="projects-section" id="projects">
            <h2 class="projects-section-header">My Projects</h2>
            <div class="projects-grid">
                <a class="project project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/rNpzdzG" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zynvp2S.jpg">
                <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Tribute Page <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p></a> <a class="project project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/MWrEErN" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/aDt3B1M.jpg">
                <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Tesla Product Page <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p></a> <a class="project project-tile" href="http://darkstar93.github.io/jquery-streetfighter/main.html" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://github.com/Darkstar93/thomas-turek-portfolio/blob/master/images/ryu.png?raw=true">
                <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Street Fighter <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p></a> <a class="project project-tile" href="http://darkstar93.github.io/stackerAJAX/" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/4e990e20126391.58b02ab778b00.jpg">
                <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Stack Overflow Reputation Builder <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p></a> <a class="project project-tile" href="http://darkstar93.github.io/Warcraft-Quiz/" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://github.com/Darkstar93/thomas-turek-portfolio/blob/master/images/quiz.jpg?raw=true">
                <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Warcraft Quiz App <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p></a> <a class="project project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/yLvzWNN" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485988412941-77a35537dae4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1196&q=80">
                <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Digital Resume <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p></a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="contact">
            <div id="contact-header">
                <h1 id="work">Lets Work Together...</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-links">
                <a class="btn contact-details" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/turekhomes/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i> LinkedIn</a> <a class="btn contact-details" href="https://github.com/Darkstar93" id="profile-link" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i> GitHub</a> <a class="btn contact-details" href="https://codepen.io/darkstar93" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-codepen"></i> CodePen</a> <a class="btn contact-details" href="mailto:thomasturek93@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-at"></i> Email</a> <a class="btn contact-details" href="tel:801-885-6352"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i> Call/Text Me</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a `<div class="container-fluid"` open tag

Comment: I've tried using container-fluid and just container and neither worked. Is there another style that I should try using?

Comment: I meant that `<div class="container-fluid"` should be `<div class="container-fluid">`, you have a typo

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I fixed the typo but it didn't fix the stacking issue unfortunately :( Do you notice any other potential flaws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet, the immediate child column div within `#name` row div, you have started a new child row element within this `#name` row.

You should not start child rows within another row element.

It should aways be `.row` > `.col` > `.row` > `.col` etc...

Never do this... `.row` > `.row` > `.col`... this will just output unexpected results

Rule of thumb... rows only ever nest child columns, and columns and other block elements can nest rows

Hopefully this might get you on the right track

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: roboto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/* nav*/


/* sections */

#welcome-section {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

#hi {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  font-size: 200vh;
  font-size: 12vw;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  padding-top: 4vh;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  color: white;
}

#job-title {
  padding-left: 5vw;
  font-size: min(3vw, 36px);
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  color: white;
}

#projects {
  background-color: #344966;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.projects-section-header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#contact {
  background-color: #6D9DC5;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#welcome-section {
  background: linear-gradient(92deg, #2e3192, #1bffff);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: bluegradient 59s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: bluegradient 59s ease infinite;
  animation: bluegradient 59s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bluegradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 51%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bluegradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 51%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}

@keyframes bluegradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 51%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}


/*  

1. Tesla Product Page
https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/MWrEErN

2. Tribute Page
https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/rNpzdzG

3. Street Fighter jQuery
http://darkstar93.github.io/jquery-streetfighter/main.html

4. Warcraft Quiz App
http://darkstar93.github.io/quiz/

5. Instagram API Hack
http://darkstar93.github.io/instagramapihack/

6. Input Survey Form
https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/rNpwROz
*/


/* Custom properties/variables  */

:root {
  --main-white: #f0f0f0;
  --main-red: #be3144;
  --main-blue: #8797B2;
  --main-gray: #000807;
}


/* Base reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* box-sizing and font sizing */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@media (max-width: 75em) {
  html {
    font-size: 60%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 61.25em) {
  html {
    font-size: 58%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  html {
    font-size: 55%;
  }
}


/* Base styles */

body {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  /* 18px */
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: var(--main-white);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4.2rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--main-white);
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Projects section */

.projects-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10rem 2rem;
  background: var(--main-blue);
}

.projects-section-header {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto 6rem auto;
  var(--main-white);
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  .projects-section-header {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}

.projects-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  padding: 28px;
}

@media (max-width: 30.625em) {
  .projects-section {
    padding: 6rem 1rem;
  }
  .projects-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

.project {
  background: var(--main-gray);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.code {
  color: var(--main-gray);
  transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
}

.project:hover .code {
  color: #ff7f50;
}

.project-image {
  height: calc(100% - 6.8rem);
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.project-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.btn-show-all {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: var(--main-gray);
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}

.btn-show-all:hover {
  background: var(--main-red);
}

.btn-show-all:hover>i {
  transform: translateX(2px);
}

.btn-show-all>i {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
}


/*blinking */

.blinking-cursor {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -moz-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -ms-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -o-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: white;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

.contact-links {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contact-details {
  font-size: 3rem;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.contact-details:hover {
  transform: translateY(8px);
  color: black;
}

i {
  color: white;
}

#work {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  .nav {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .nav-list {
    margin: 0 1rem;
  }
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  background: var(--main-blue);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="background">
  <nav class="nav" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li><a href="#welcome-section">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-start" id="name">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color: rgb(136, 84, 20);">
          <h1 id="hi">Hi<br> I am<br> Thomas
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 justify-content-end" style="background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);">
          <p>I'm highly motivated and passionate about development and creative design. I challenge myself every day to be a little better and increase my skills. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1 id="job-title"></h1>
  </section>
  <section class="projects-section" id="projects">
    <h2 class="projects-section-header">My Projects</h2>
    <div class="projects-grid">
      <a class="project project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/rNpzdzG" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/zynvp2S.jpg">
        <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Tribute Page <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>
      <a class="project project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/MWrEErN" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/aDt3B1M.jpg">
        <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Tesla Product Page <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>
      <a class="project project-tile" href="http://darkstar93.github.io/jquery-streetfighter/main.html" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://github.com/Darkstar93/thomas-turek-portfolio/blob/master/images/ryu.png?raw=true">
        <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Street Fighter <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>
      <a class="project project-tile" href="http://darkstar93.github.io/stackerAJAX/" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/4e990e20126391.58b02ab778b00.jpg">
        <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Stack Overflow Reputation Builder <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>
      <a class="project project-tile" href="http://darkstar93.github.io/Warcraft-Quiz/" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://github.com/Darkstar93/thomas-turek-portfolio/blob/master/images/quiz.jpg?raw=true">
        <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Warcraft Quiz App <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>
      <a class="project project-tile" href="https://codepen.io/darkstar93/pen/yLvzWNN" target="_blank"><img alt="project" class="project-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485988412941-77a35537dae4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1196&q=80">
        <p class="project-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> Digital Resume <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="contact">
    <div id="contact-header">
      <h1 id="work">Lets Work Together...</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-links">
      <a class="btn contact-details" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/turekhomes/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i> LinkedIn</a>
      <a class="btn contact-details" href="https://github.com/Darkstar93" id="profile-link" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i> GitHub</a>
      <a class="btn contact-details" href="https://codepen.io/darkstar93" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-codepen"></i> CodePen</a>
      <a class="btn contact-details" href="mailto:thomasturek93@gmail.com"><i class="fas fa-at"></i> Email</a>
      <a class="btn contact-details" href="tel:801-885-6352"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i> Call/Text Me</a>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```